# Generate a Random Decimal within a range in Ruby/Rails or Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

Is there a way on Faker to generate a random decimal between 0-1?
https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/issues/1834

```
Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits= 2, r_digits= 2).within(range: 0..1)
```

The above does not work. Error:

```
 undefined method `within' for "12.4" String
```

12.4 being the random number that's generated

If I can't use faker, is there a way in Ruby to generate this? I just need to generate a number with 2 decimal places between 0 and 1

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Expected result, actual result?

Comment: @Pascal updated the question

Comment: Seems like `decimal` returns a String and you try to call the `within` method on it. Where does this method come from?

Comment: @Pascal the within method is from the Faker library

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following:

```
Faker::Number.between(from: 0.0, to: 1.0).round(2)
```

**Source:**

- [Faker::Number.between docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/faker-ruby/faker/master/Faker%2FNumber.between).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rand.round(2)
```

`rand` generates a random number, `round` rounds it to the desired number of decimals. This might generate a number that has LESS than two decimal digits (e.g. `0.5`).
If you want to enforce this you can format the random number to a String:

```
Kernel.format("%.2f", rand)
```

Where `%f` is the formating as *float* and `%.2f` is specific for two decimal digits.
You can actually ommit `Kernel` and just call `format` or use `%` like so:

```
"%.2f" % rand
```

(i prefer `Kernel.format`, seems more reeadable to me)

Now this poses another problem:

```
pattern = "%.2f"
Kernel.format(pattern, 0) # => "0.00"
Kernel.format(pattern, 0.9999999) # => "1.00"
```

because it gets rounded up when formatting the number is suddenly not smaller than `1`. If by between you meant NOT INCLUDING 1 you will need to tweak it some more:

```
Kernel.format(pattern, 0.floor(2)) # => "0.00"
Kernel.format(pattern, 0.9999999.floor(2)) # => "0.99"
```